# Retrieve Result from Ajax Process

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I need a way of retrieving data from a processing script into a Request page using Ajax, PHP. The code below shows this error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 13 of the JSON data
>   var data4=JSON.parse(data4);

Please, note that I have search  but have not been able to get solution. So, I thought maybe there is a way of passing the result to the requesting page without using `json_encode`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/scripts/newJquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select.partno").change(function() {
            var selectedCustomer = $(".partno option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process-grpid.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    custid: selectedCustomer
                }
            }).done(function(data4) {
                var data4 = JSON.parse(data4); //Error Area
                //using php-mysql before
                $("#desc").html(data4.ref);
                $("#purch").html(data4.lprice);

            });
        });
    });
</script>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Code/Part NO:</th>
            <?php 
           include("db_connection.php");
          $s = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tab_stock ORDER BY itemName ASC");?>
                <td>
                    <select name="partno" class="partno">
                        <option>Select PartNo</option>
                        <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                        <?php while($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($s)){ ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $rw['itemName'];?>">
                                <?php echo $rw['itemName'];?>
                            </option>
                            <?php };?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <th>Description:</th>
                <td id="desc"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Last Purchase Price:</th>
            <td id="purch"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

process-grpid.php (Processing Script)

```
<?php    
    if (isset($_POST["custid"])) {            
        include 'includes/session.php';
        include 'includes/db_connection.php';
        include 'includes/functions.php';
        $partid = $_POST["custid"];
        if ($partid !== 'Select PartNo') {
            $gets = "SELECT * FROM tab_stock WHERE itemName='" . $partid . "'";
            $get  = mysqli_query($connection, $gets);

            $row    = mysqli_fetch_array($get);
            $desc   = $row['description'];
            $lprice = $row['Rate'];
            if ($partid == 'N/A') {
                $res["sta"]    = 0;
                $res["ref"]    = "<input type='text'   class='desc' name='descr'  size='50' required='required'/>";
                $res["lprice"] = "<input type='text' id='puch' name='lastpur'   required='required'/>";
            } else {
                $res["sta"]    = 1;
                $res["ref"]    = "<input type='text'  value='$desc' class='desc' name='descr'  size='50' readonly='readonly' required='required'/>";
                $res["lprice"] = "<input type='text' id='puch' name='lastpur' value='$lprice'  readonly='readonly' required='required'/>";

            }
            echo json_encode($res);
        }            
    }
?>
```

When I run this Application, it shows an error of SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 13 of the JSON data
var data4=JSON.parse(data4)
But when checked with Firebug, in the HTML and RESPONSE TAB, it shows the expected result. Question, what alternative way of getting result from a processing script to the requesting page, withput uisng json_encode and JSON.parse(response)?

Comment: May be you have white-spaces after  ?> try to remove it

Comment: @KostyaShkryob: white space after ?> of which script. Processing script or what?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez: Yes, they have the proper format

Comment: Have you run the response through something like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) just to double-check that it is valid?

Comment: You should remove ?> in your PHP script. It is recommended to omit closing tags if there is no HTML code after PHP (http://php.net/basic-syntax.phptags).

Comment: {"sta":1,"ref":"<input type='text'  value='BEARING OUTER' class='desc' name='descr'  size
='50' readonly='readonly' required='required'\/>","lprice":"<input type='text' id='puch' name='lastpur'
 value='1000'  readonly='readonly' required='required'\ />"}

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
dataType: "json"
```

of the call ajax

**Update**:
If the configuration is dataType: json, you'll get a javascript object is no longer necessary JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and made some tests. Next code works for me:

**test.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
function myAjax () {
var selectedCustomer = 1;                               // DATA FOR PHP.
$.ajax( { type : "POST",
          url  : "test.php",
          data : { "custid" : selectedCustomer },       // DATA FOR PHP.
          success: function ( data4 ) {
            var data4 = JSON.parse( data4 );
            alert( data4.custid );
            alert( data4.sta );
            alert( data4.ref );
            alert( data4.lprice );
            $("#desc").html( data4.ref );              // <TD> IN <BODY>.
          },
          error: function ( xhr ) {
            alert( "error" );
          }
        });
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myAjax()">echo hello</button>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="desc"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST[ "custid" ] ) )
   { $res = array();
     $res["custid"] = $_POST[ "custid" ];
     $res["sta"]    = 2;
     $res["ref"]    = "<input type='text' class='desc' name='descr' size='50' required='required'/>";
     $res["lprice"] = "<input type='text' id='puch' name='lastpur' required='required'/>";
     echo json_encode( $res );
   }
?>
```

Notice I deleted the ajax line `dataType : "json",`, because as soon as I include it this code throws an error. Copy-paste previous codes in two files called "test.html" and "text.php", they work fine.

Comment: no... you fundamentally changed it, yours doesn't involve ajax, where it actually is a json string being returned from php that DOES need to be parsed. it's just that jQuery is doing that part for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
echo json_encode($res);
```

Use:

```
echo json_encode(array('res' => $res));
```

And instead of:

```
var data4 = JSON.parse(data4);
```

Use:

```
var d = data4.res;
```

And than use "d" like an array. Here is the JS code I am trying to tell you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select.partno").change(function() {
        var selectedCustomer = $(".partno option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process-grpid.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {custid: selectedCustomer}
        }).done(function(data4) {
            var d = data4.res;
            $("#desc").html(d['ref']);
            $("#purch").html(d['lprice']);

        });
    });
});
```

If still there is an error, it is probably in the usage of "d" and you can change d['ref'] to d[1] and d['lprice'] to d[2].

I see that there is also a mistake when trying to concatenate $desc and $lprice to the input strings.

```
$res["ref"]    = "<input type='text'  value='" . $desc. "' class='desc' name='descr'  size='50' readonly='readonly' required='required'/>";
$res["lprice"] = "<input type='text' id='puch' name='lastpur' value='" . $lprice . "'  readonly='readonly' required='required'/>";
```

And a plus... if you use these variables only if $partid != 'N/A', why don't you move the query to inside the else statment? Doing this, you avoid to execute the query all the time.

```
if ($partid !== 'Select PartNo') {

        if ($partid == 'N/A') {

            $res["sta"]    = 0;
            $res["ref"]    = "<input type='text'   class='desc' name='descr'  size='50' required='required'/>";
            $res["lprice"] = "<input type='text' id='puch' name='lastpur'   required='required'/>";
        } else {
            $gets = "SELECT * FROM tab_stock WHERE itemName='" . $partid . "'";
            $get  = mysqli_query($connection, $gets);
            $row    = mysqli_fetch_array($get);

            $res["sta"]    = 1;
            $res["ref"]    = "<input type='text'  value='" . $row['description'] . "' class='desc' name='descr'  size='50' readonly='readonly' required='required'/>";
            $res["lprice"] = "<input type='text' id='puch' name='lastpur' value='" . $row['Rate'] . "'  readonly='readonly' required='required'/>";

        }
        echo json_encode($res);
    }
```

Comment: I updated my answer with more code. I hope it works for you now.

Comment: It is not displaying any error. but it wasn't displaying the Result on the requested page as well. But it you use Firebug on fireefox and check the HTML, RESPONSE Tab , The correct JSON result is correctly displayed. SO, why is it not showing on the Requested PAGE?

Comment: I noticed that you wrote value='$desc' and value='$lprice' in your input strings. If you are trying to write the value of these variables, you'll need to concatenate them to the string. Maybe there is something due to this new problem. I will update my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Try not using the JSON.parse at all ... as you get a native JavaScript Object back, not a JSON String ...